# Building Neural Network over and over with same parameters give different result

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

I am using tensorflow 2.3.0

I am creating RNN to predict stock prices, whenever I Restart jupyter notebook & re-Run all my code it outputs very different predictions. Why is it so when all hyperparameters are exactly the same?

I know this is very basic question but can someone tell me or tell me where I can read about it?

Here is my code:

```
def GetStockData(ticker_name, period, start_date, end_date):
    tickerData = yf.Ticker(ticker_name)
    df = tickerData.history(period=period, start=start_date, end=end_date)
    return df

full_nvda_df = GetStockData("NVDA", "1d", "2016-01-01", "2020-10-10")
nvda_df = full_nvda_df[["Close"]].copy()
train_df = nvda_df[:1000]
test_df = nvda_df[1000:]

train_arr = np.array(train_df)
test_arr = np.array(test_df)

for i in range(30, len(train_df)):
    X_train.append(train_arr[i-30:i])
    y_train.append(train_arr[i, 0])
    
X_train, y_train = np.array(X_train), np.array(y_train)



np.random.seed(1337)
model = tf.keras.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.LSTM(units=60, activation='relu', return_sequences=True, input_shape=(X_train.shape[1], 1) ),
    tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2),
    
    tf.keras.layers.LSTM(units=60, activation='relu', return_sequences=True),
    tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2),
    
    tf.keras.layers.LSTM(units=80, activation='relu', return_sequences=True),
    tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2),
    
    tf.keras.layers.LSTM(units=120, activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2),
    
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=1)
])

model.summary()
model.compile(loss = "mean_squared_error",
              optimizer = "adam")
```

Comment: What do you mean by "restart and run". Are you re-training your model? Or your model is trained (and fixed) and you get different result on inference?

Comment: restart my notebook and run all the code again from start to finish

Comment: We do not know what is in your notebook. Are you retraining model every time or not?

Comment: Does restarting jupyter notebook and training model again retrain?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**UPDATE (TF >= 2.9)**

Starting from TF 2.9 (TF >= 2.9), if you want your TF models to run deterministically, the following lines need to be added at the beginning of the program.

```
import tensorflow as tf

tf.keras.utils.set_random_seed(1)
tf.config.experimental.enable_op_determinism()
```

Important note: The first line sets the random seed for the following : Python, NumPy and TensorFlow. The second line makes each TensorFlow operation deterministic.

**OLDER THAN TF 2.8**

Without seeing your code, I may only infer that it is because the weights of the neural network are randomly initialized; when you refer to

> "configurations are all the same"

you may refer to the hyperparameters which you actually set them from the beginning or iterate over a set to determine the most suitable values for them on your particular problem.

However, the `weights` are randomly initialized and this will inevitably lead to a different convergence path of your network, and thus evidently a different local optimum (i.e. different results).

The only way to ensure reproducibility(as far as I am aware of) is to "seed everything", like below:

```
random.seed(seed)
np.random.seed(seed)
os.environ['PYTHONHASHSEED'] = str(seed)
tf.random.set_seed(seed)
```

According to this thread on GitHub https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/14986,

In TensorFlow >= `2.5`, one can use `TF_DETERMINISTIC_OPS=1` is also a solution to ensure the reproducibility.

However it is mentioned that there are still some GPU Ops not reproducible, and that perfect reproducibility between the results CPU and GPU may never be achieved.

Comment: Yes, my expectation is confirmed; you change nothing in the code but you just rerun it

Comment: So if you are using Rnn for translation everytime it will translate differently unless I seed everything?

Comment: Not necessarily. You will reach a different local optimum, which means that your set of weights would be different. If your set of weights is different, this could result (but not necessarily) to another translation(perhaps first 4 words from the translation the same but the 5-th one different). Note that this is available to all problems/tasks with neural networks and it is not available only in the case of machine translation.

Comment: You are welcome. Should you have any more questions I would be willing/glad to help.